# How to globally set the font for all MetaPost drawings in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, metapost

When I add labels to MetaPost drawings in ConTeXt, it does not use the fonts for the rest of the document but appears to be using either a math font or the default fonts used by ConTeXt. I can set the font for specific items, e.g. `label("\sourcefont This will appear with the correct font", (25,75));` but doesn't seem to follow the philosophy of ConTeXt, and I have to set the font for every single label (I have many hundreds). Is there a global way to set it, either for within all MetaPost drawings in the document, or in the very least, at the start of the MetaPost, which will be used everywhere a label is placed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default font for Metafun labels is set in [`meta-ini.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/c49d2942bae7074f3bd4c04b6ee895cee1697ca3/tex/context/base/mkiv/meta-ini.mkiv#L451-L457) to `MetafunDefault` which is a synonym for `Regular` which is usually the serif text font, by default Latin Modern Roman.

Thus you have two options to change the font.

1. Reset the `MetafunDefault` synonym to a font of your choice:

   ```
   \definefontsynonym [MetafunDefault] [file:texgyrepagella-regular*default]
   \starttext
   This is the text font

   \startMPcode
   label("This is the Metafun font", origin) ;
   \stopMPcode
   \stoptext
   ```
2. Use `MPinitializations` do set the `defaultfont` variable to something different.  This is the documented approach, see 10.3 “Labels” in the [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf).

   ```
   \startMPinitializations
   defaultfont := "file:texgyrepagella-regular*default" ;
   \stopMPinitializations
   \starttext
   This is the text font

   \startMPcode
   label("This is the Metafun font", origin) ;
   \stopMPcode
   \stoptext
   ```

Comment: I see in one of my files (probably from the list) `\startMPenvironment \setupbodyfont[9pt]\stopMPenvironment`. Is that a worse solution than the ones you suggest for some reason?

Comment: @mickep From reading the Metafun manual it is not clear to me whether this is equivalent or orthogonal to my answer.  You should definitely post it as an additional answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `textstyle` key of [`MPinstance`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupMPinstance) for changing the font. The default metapost figures are drawn using the `metafun` instance. So, you can simply do:

```
\setupMPinstance[metafun][textstyle={\sourcefont}]
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\setupbodyfont[modern,10pt]

\setupMPinstance[metafun][textstyle={\switchtobodyfont[pagella,10pt]}]

\starttext
This is the text font

\startMPcode
label("This is the Metafun font", origin) ;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hesitated to give this as an answer, since I read in [the MetaFun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) that the `\startMPenvironemnt \stopMPenvironment` is merely for mkii, and not needed in mkiv (see section 10.2).

In any case, I have successfully used this method for years:

```
\setupbodyfont[bonum]

\startbuffer[lefigure]
\startplacefigure[location=nonumber]
\startMPcode
draw fullcircle scaled 2cm;
label.rt(textext("east"),(1cm,0));
label.top(textext("north"),(0,1cm));
label.lft(textext("west"),(-1cm,0));
label.bot(textext("south"),(0,-1cm));
\stopMPcode
\stopplacefigure
\stopbuffer

\startTEXpage[offset=0.25in]
Normal text set with bonum. MetaPost figures uses the same font:

\getbuffer[lefigure]

\startMPenvironment
\setupbodyfont[latinmodern,ss,6pt]
\stopMPenvironment

Efter we have changed the bodyfont inside a \tex{startMPenvironment} \tex{stopMPenvironment}
we get this new font in our MetaPost figures:

\getbuffer[lefigure]
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: image showing result with different fonts in different parts]

I would not suggest to do such changes more than once, but once and for all. Typically:

```
\setupbodyfont[bonum]
\startMPenvironment
\setupbodyfont[6pt]
\stopMPenvironment

\starttext
...
\stoptext
```